# Fortran Error: Syntax error in DATA statement at (1)

Tags: fortran

Recieving error from console, saying i have a syntax error, not quite understanding how because new to fortran

```
data pi, ealf, eals, xray, niter, densi, msi, na
1    /3.14159, 35.0, 22.0, 1486.7, 100, 2.35, 28.0, 6.023e23/
```

Error: Syntax error in DATA statement at (1)

Comment: If this is fixed-form source code and the line of code you show is split onto two lines, then the `1` after `na` needs to be in column 6.  If this is free-form source code, the `1` should not be there.

Comment: Can you edit the code so that it is exactly the way it appears in the source file?  I'd recommend to use code fences to surround it i.e. three backticks on a line immediately before and immediately after the code.  Also, please confirm the extension of the source file i.e. .f, .f90, or something else.

Comment: @Craig I updated it apologies, and the file extension is .f90

Comment: This is not how you continue lines in free form Fortran (extension .f90).

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава how would i continue from that line, I am confused I inherited this legacy prog

Comment: See the link to the question of which is this one a duplicate and read the answers there. The link is at the top of your question.

Comment: Comment here, if you do not understand the answers there, but do read those answers. They contain examples as well.